# Strange behaviour in React component that includes message listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm working on a component for a chrome extension that needs to listen for messages passed from other parts of the extension and update the display based on those messages.

A simplified version of what I thought should work is below but it does not do what I would expect.

This snippet successfully receives the message and calls the increment function, but never increments passed 1, with the log just repeating `Incrementing 0 -> 1`

```
// app.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = React.useState(0)

    function increment() {
        console.log("Incrementing ", counter, " -> ", (counter + 1));
        setCounter(counter + 1)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => increment())
    }, [ ])

    return <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
```

After some experimentation I discovered that if I set an intermediary value, and then update the counter via a seperate effect, as in the snippet below, it works exactly as I would expect.

```
// app.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = React.useState(0)
    const [ message, setMessage ] = React.useState()

    function increment() {
        console.log("Incrementing ", counter, " -> ", (counter + 1));
        setCounter(counter + 1)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => setMessage(message))
    }, [ ])

    React.useEffect(() => increment(), [ message ])

    return <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
```

The message sending is identical in both versions and working as expected in both cases. It is just a sendMessage call from a content script.

```
// contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'INCREMENT' })
```

This solution is acceptable, but I'm having trouble understanding why the second works as expected when the first does not.

Is anyone able to explain this behaviour?

Comment: Can you show you are sending event in the first solution

Comment: The event sending is identical in both cases, and represents identically if logs are added to the message listener.

It's just a call from sendMessage, coming from a content script
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'INCREMENT' })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stale closure problem:

```
   function increment() {
        console.log("Incrementing ", counter, " -> ", (counter + 1));
        setCounter(counter + 1)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => increment())
    }, [ ])
```

`increment` will always be from first render (hence also `counter`), because the `useEffect` was run only once due to empty array as dependency.

One way to change your code will be:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        // By moving increment inside useEffect it is not needed to put as dependency
        function increment() {
            // by using functional set state we always have access to recent state
            setCounter(ps => ps + 1)
        }
    
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => increment())
    
        return () => {        
            // You can handle remove listener here        
        }
    }, [])
```

But [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) is more reading about this topic.

Comment: Oh wow seems so obvious once you mention that. Makes total sense - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the message listener before sending event

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = React.useState(0)

    function increment() {
        console.log("Incrementing ", counter, " -> ", (counter + 1));
        setCounter(counter + 1)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      //first
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => increment())
      //then
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'INCREMENT' })
        
    }, [ ])

    return <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
}
```

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render()

Comment: I think there was a bit of a misunderstanding.

The sendMessage call happens in a seperate file, which is a content script embedded in a 3rd party site.

Receiving the message, and having it trigger the `increment()` function is working as expected in both cases, it's just that in the first the state doesn't seem to be persisted correctly and the value never changes from 1